# Yii2: call custom method in class User from view

Tags: view, model, yii2, yii2-user

I would like to extend my own user model, with a function called getFirstname. 
The function should return a custom field in the database.

But when I extend the user model. It says "Calling unknown method: yii\web\User::getFirstname()"

My user model in app\models\user.
I have removed methods in the file, that are not relevant for this problem.

```php
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * User model
 *
 */
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByEmail($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['user_email' => $username]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->user_firstname;
    }  
}
```

My config file:

```php
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'thepaXucufrE2pefRethaxetrusacRu3',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'loginUrl' => ['login/sign-in'],
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    ],
];
```

And in my view file:

```
<?= Yii::$app->user->getFirstname() ?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?= Yii::$app->user->identity->getFirstname() ?>

<!-- or -->

<?= Yii::$app->user->identity->firstname ?>
```

With `Yii::$app->user` you just get the *user component*. The [*User component*](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html) class comment tells you:

> User is the class for the "user" application component that manages
>   the user authentication status.

So it is not the actual user that you get with `Yii::$app->user`, it is the managing component. With `identity` or `getIdentity()` of this class you get the user object that is implementing the IdentityInterface. And when you have a look: your User class implements this interface. And in your configuration you tell the *user component* that it should use exactly your User class.

Comment: Works! Thanks for the detailed description!

Answer (score 0):

The `User` class with the `getFirstname` method is in the `\app\models` namespace, but the one being called in your view is in the `yii\web` namespace. You should change the code to use `\app\models\User`.